# Why is C++ std::optional::operator*() not declared as noexcept?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

When running a static analyzer over my code, I've come across std::optional::operator*() not being declared as noexcept. It would seem to me that there is no good reason for the operator to throw as one is expected to verify if the optional is engaged PRIOR to fetching its value.

Is anyone able to clarify why this decision was made?

Answer (score 2):

Found justification as to why noexcept was not used, buried within the std::optional proposal n3672:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html

> The observers that access the contained value — operator* and
> operator-> — are not declared as noexcept(true) even though they have
> no good reason to throw. This is because they impose a precondition
> that optional object shall be engaged, and as per observations from
> N3248[6], library vendors may need to use exceptions to test if the
> implementation has all the necessary precondition-checking code
> inside. These observer functions are still required not to throw
> exceptions.